# What does "AMGP" stand for?

Tags: terminology, sec

I'm now analyzing XBRL document.
https://www.sec.gov/xbrl/site/xbrl.shtml

There are namespaces `gaap` that stands for "Generally accepted accounting principles" and `dei` for "Document and Entity Information".

But I couldn't find out what does `amgp` stands for that is one of the namespaces of XBRL file.

Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Can you provide a link to somewhere on the SEC site that mentions AMGP, or an example of where you see AMGP in an XBRL file?

Comment: For example in this file https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1621697/000116552716000962/0001165527-16-000962.txt

Comment: It stands for Ambergroup. See the top of the document. They appear to use `agmp` as the name for fields they've defined and as part of the filename.

Comment: I see, the namespace is only for this company. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for Ambergroup. See the top of the document. They appear to use `agmp` as the name for fields they've defined and as part of the filename.